# SQL - select the first occurence of a customer's order when look at any order

Tags: mysql, sql

When looking at an order in my company's database, I would like to also find the order_id of the first order made by the customer who issued the order that I am currently looking at.

Among other things, that would help me to know if the order that I am looking at is the first order ever made by the customer or not.

- The orders are stored in database.orders.The orders have a unique order_id (int 10) and contain a column customer_id. I usually sort the orders by different criteria (price, voucher code used, date, ...)
- The customers are stored in database.customers.The customers have a unique customer id (int 10).

So for example when looking at all the orders issued by the customers who used a voucher with the code "VOUCHER123" or "COUPON123" and with a price above 1000 EUR, I would like to get

```
order_id  | customer_id | voucher_code | price | order_id_first_order_ever
1000      | 50          | coupon123    | 1300  | 845
1100      | 56          | voucher123   | 2005  | 1100
```

I do not really know how to do get the last column. Should I use inner requests? Is it feasible at all in just one request?

I am quite puzzled by this and any assistance would be keenly welcome.

I am using My SQL Workbench.

Best regards,

Jean-Baptiste

Comment: table definitions and existing SQL query attempts make answering your question simpler. If you can edit your post to include these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

The solution is to use an inner join on the main table, as follow:

```
SELECT
    database.orders.order_id,
    database.customers.customer_id,
    database.orders.voucher_code,
    database.orders.price,
    MIN(previous_orders.order_id) AS "order_id_first_order_ever"
FROM
    database.orders,
    INNER JOIN database.customers ON database.customers.customer_id = database.orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN database.orders AS previous_orders ON database.orders.customer_id = previous_order.customer_id**
WHERE
    database.orders.voucher_code = "voucher123" OR
    database.orders.voucher_code = "coupon123"
GROUP BY
    database.orders.order_id
```

And it yields what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If I my understanding towards your question is correct, then the below query should give you the expected results.

```
SELECT order_id, customer_id, voucher_code, price, order_id_first_order_ever 
FROM orders 
WHERE voucher_code="voucher123" AND price>1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lesser order_id values for earlier orders:

```
select order_id, 
       customer_id, 
       voucher_code, 
       price,
       (select order_id 
         where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id  
          from database.orders t2 
      order by order_id limit 1) as 'order_id_first_order_ever' 
  from database.orders t1 
 where voucher_code in ("VOUCHER123", "COUPON123") 
   and price > 1000 
 order by order_id;
```

For order_id that does not increase monotonic, another field has to be chosen for the order by clause in the subselect.